# how can i implement the flag -l and -a to my own ls function

Tags: c, environment, flags, ls, argv

```
#include<stdio.h> 
 #include<stdlib.h> 
 #include <sys/types.h> 
 #include <dirent.h> 
  
 int main(void) 
 { 
    char *curr_dir = NULL; 
    DIR *dp = NULL; 
    struct dirent *dptr = NULL; 
    unsigned int count = 0; 
  
    curr_dir = getenv("PWD"); 
    if(NULL == curr_dir) 
    { 
        printf("\n ERROR : Could not get the working directory\n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 
  
    dp = opendir((const char*)curr_dir); 
    if(NULL == dp) 
    { 
        printf("\n ERROR : Could not open the working directory\n"); 
        return -1; 
    } 
  
    printf("\n"); 
    for(count = 0; NULL != (dptr = readdir(dp)); count++) 
    { 
        // Check if the name of the file/folder begins with '.' 
        // If yes, then do not display it. 
        if(dptr->d_name[0] != '.') 
            printf("%s  ",dptr->d_name); 
    } 
  
    return 0; 
 }
```

Build a program that works like ls and accepts 2 flags (-a and -l). It won't be interactive, it would be just a call to the program with the flags as arguments. So in that order of ideas.

hls -a should behave like ls -a
hls -l should behave like ls -l

Conditions.

- Zero memory leaks. (Valgrind should give 0 in everything)
- Code should compile in Ubuntu 14.04 with all flags
- One single file.

Comment: [getopt](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html). Assuming you are allowed to use libraries and assuming you are asking about how to parse the flag and not how to implement the functionality of the flag. Please clarify the post if it is the latter.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** see **man ls** and have a look at what the arguments **-a** and **-l** are

> **-a** do not ignore entries starting with **.**
>
> **-l** use a long listing format

**2.** have a look at this page: [C Main function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function)

**3.** iterate over the **argv** array and check for

- **a** -> set status flag (e.g. *bool is_a_set*)
- **l** -> set status flag (e.g. *bool is_l_set*)

**4.** open desired directory (**opendir**)

**5.** while **readdir** does not return **NULL**

- if *status_a* is not set and **d_name** starts with a dot -> continue
- else call your print function

**6.** print function implementation:

- if *status_l* is set, print long format (whatever that is)
- else print only **d_name**
- print additional separator

**7.** cleanup and exit